# My application's text and size becomes smaller and smaller until it finally crashes. Why?

Tags: android

I am using Samsung Galaxy S 4G (the new one). Previously, I tested this on the Dell Streak Tablet phone, as well as the HTC Desire, and it performed perfectly.

But now, when I start the application things are misaligned, and as I use the application the text becomes smaller and smaller, the graphics become skewed, until finally the app crashes.

Why is this? And how can I fix it?

I am NOT changing the size of anything ... like I said, I've used the same application on two other devices and nothing has made a difference. I am currently thinking it maybe has to do with the Manifest file, an SDK version issue? I read about a similar issue when someone changed language, the text got smaller, which was fixed with

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer">
```

so I am looking into that.

Edit: The logcat output:

```
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to          start activity  ComponentInfo{a.company.organization/a.company.organization.travel.TravelTab}:     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity    ComponentInfo{a.company.organization/a.company.organization.travel.TravelMap}:   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #130: Error inflating class <unknown>
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{a.company.organization/a.company.organization.travel.TravelMap}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #130: Error inflating class <unknown>09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2503)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at a.company.organization.tabcontrol.TabBarActivity.displayCurrentScreen(TabBarActivity.java:159)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at a.company.organization.tabcontrol.TabBarActivity.displayCurrentScreen(TabBarActivity.java:137)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at a.company.organization.tabcontrol.TabBarActivity.setCurrentTab(TabBarActivity.java:422)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at a.company.organization.tabcontrol.TabBarActivity.onCreate(TabBarActivity.java:369)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     ... 11 more
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #130: Error inflating class <unknown>
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at a.company.organization.travel.TravelMap.onCreate(TravelMap.java:66)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     ... 20 more
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:108)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     ... 32 more
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-mdpi/carousel_top_bar.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f020087
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1714)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:118)
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     ... 36 more
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
09-21 15:18:34.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7377):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Nati
09-21 15:18:34.313: WARN/ActivityManager(6572):   Force finishing activity a.company.organization/.travel.TravelTab
09-21 15:18:34.316: ERROR/(6572): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

Comment: We'll need to see some code in order to diagnose the problem.  Please edit your question with a brief section of code.

Comment: Add some codes. And also put some logcat debug outputs.

Comment: You didn't by chance use the DrinkMeShrinkMe object anywhere in your project did you?

Comment: You're shrinking something over and over again, but without seeing your code we can't tell you what it is or how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this issue, you should restrict the sdk version. To do that for 2.0 and above add:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" android:maxSdkVersion="5" />
```

You should also modify the Manifest file to include:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
 android:largeScreens="true" android:resizeable="false"
 android:normalScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true"></supports-screens>
```

The resources I used for finding out about  is [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html), and for API Level to Platform level check I used [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)